# How to project point cloud on a plane with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, point-clouds

I am trying to present `a point cloud` and its projection with `OpenGL` on the plane normal to the line connecting the two most distant points. I have succeed in presenting `the point cloud` on the scene with an orthonormal system. I have found the two farthest point in the cloud. And I found the plan on which I projected.

I tried to make this projection but envin. 
I tried with the transformation matrices as `GL_PROJECTION` but envin.

Can someone give me hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the coordinates of the projected points by mathematical formulas, then draw them with OpenGL.

Take a look at [this link](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_affine)

Answer (score 0):

You can [drop a perpendicular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines#Using_trigonometry) from each point to your found plane, and compute its foot point on the plane. Then draw another point there.